# jQuery list icon change

Tags: jquery, list, dynamic, html

I have a drop down list and some code to perform the operation to drop down the children and also change the list icon: Full set-up on this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Gwbfd/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.drawer').hide();
  $('.handle').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).closest('ul').toggleClass('expanded');
    $(this).closest('ul').toggleClass('collapsed');
                               });  
                             });
```

The list is multi-tiered, and the problem I am having is there are multiple children of the second tier, and when I click one of the second tier children, it changes the icons of both children.

Comment: Side note: Cache $(this) into something like var $this = $(this), there is an overhead to your repeated and unnecessary calls to jQuery.

Comment: @jholloman There's no significant overhead to `$(this)` which is a direct element reference, only to repeated use of things like `$('#some .selector')`.

Comment: In any case, the `.closest('ul')` calls could be chained as `$(this).closest('li').toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed')` for what it's worth (not much really).

Comment: @Plynx caching the selection even though it's a direct reference is still ~20% speed increase. jQuery is expensive no matter what you call it for. (Though nothing compares to a DOM lookup) http://jsperf.com/cost-of-repeated

Comment: @jholloman Neat test! Part of this is the overhead of any function call, and in my tests this is dwarfed by doing things to the DOM (as opposed to getting non-compositing information like id). I wouldn't worry about this unless in some kind of tight loop or rapidly refiring event, and if I did have reason to be worried about it, looks like I'd make it a direct javascript to DOM call anyway. My takeaway is, program in a way that reads and writes easier for you the programmer while using JQuery, since it's a literate DSL, not performance code. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style the `li` elements directly, and that involves a few modifications to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.drawer').hide();
   $('li:has(ul)').addClass("collapsed");
   $('.handle').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings().slideToggle('slow');
      $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('expanded');
      $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

and in the CSS:

```
li.expanded{
list-style: outside url('http://www.theparisreview.org/images/expand-icon.png') none;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

li.collapsed{
    list-style: outside url('http://www.theparisreview.org/images/collapse-icon.png') none;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gwbfd/8/

Comment: I think I love you. I don't have enough reputation to vote you, but I'll have to send you a fruitcake for Christmas or something.

Answer (score 0):

You're adjusting the liststyle for the entire list which contains both secondary items. You need to change the class at the li level instead of the ul level.

```
  $('.handle').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings().slideToggle('slow');
    $this.closest('li').toggleClass('expanded');
    $this.closest('li').toggleClass('collapsed');
                               });  
                             });
```

This isn't a perfect fix but shows a somewhat working version. I just changed the ul to li and updated the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gwbfd/5/